# Thunderbird 15.0.1 cannot use Exchange 2003 SMTP

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2003, telnet, thunderbird

I'm having the strangest time getting a Thunderbird email client to connect to my Exchange 2003 server.

I got the incoming IMAP account set up no problem, and I can receive mail. However sending mail will not work no matter what SMTP settings I enter. After checking the server, the proper settings should be port 25 with no authentication or connection security, which I have entered. I can ping the hostname of the server from the client machine in question. The Thunderbird error message I get is:

> "Sending of message failed. The message could not be sent because the
>   connection to SMTP server -hostname omitted- was lost in the middle of
>   the transaction."

So I went to the server and double checked the settings for Exchange's SMTP stuff. I have it correct. I tried to telnet (on the server) to **localhost 25**. It appears to connect and then disconnect immediately, no message, no nothing. When I telnet to other ports (POP-110 for example) I get proper connection messages and a stable connection. There are no firewalls on either the client or the server. There's a firewall on the network but LAN->LAN traffic is unrestricted.

I can reproduce the Thunderbird error on a second client, and I can't get any client to be able to telnet in.

EDIT: I'm having the same problem with Zimbra Desktop.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Disable the Connection filter on the properties of the SMTP Virtual Server and try both the Thunderbird and Telnet test again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Exchange System Manager, Org/Servers/ServerName/Protocols/SMTP/ Properties on your Virtual Server.

Access tab....
Authentication - Anonymous should be checked

Connection Control - All except...

Relay (key) - Make sure bottom "allow those that authenticate" is checked. I would also, for grins, add the IP of your client to the lest. At least this way you have something to test with.

N

Comment: Thank you! It was the Connection Control that I had missed. For some reason the subnet had been added as a single computer entry (eg. 10.0.0.0 instead of 10.0.0.0 (255.0.0.0)) and 127.0.0.1 wasn't in the list at all. When I deleted the single entry for the subnet and readded it properly as a group of hosts, everything began to work. I'm not sure if adding 127.0.0.1 is actually necessary, but I added it as well.